Support any custom component in TinyMCE
I want to allow any custom elements such as <my-comp /> or <media-plus><img></media-plus> from the TinyMCE code editor without knowing up-front which elements will be defined.
The custom_elements option doesn't work for this because it only allows a pre-determined list of elements.

By using the onInit event, you can add a listener to BeforeSetContent event to the Editor like this to whitelist all custom components:
(event: EditorEvent<BeforeSetContentEvent>) => {
  const { content, target } = event;
  const { schema }: { schema: Schema } = target;

  // Parse the content to find custom elements
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html');

  // Get all unique tags in the document
  const tags = new Set(
    Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('*')).map((e) =>
      e.tagName.toLowerCase(),
    ),
  );

  // Get the default elements defined in the TinyMCE schema
  const defaultElements = Object.keys(schema.elements);

  // Filter out custom tags (non-standard HTML elements)
  const customTags = Array.from(tags).filter(
    (tag) => !defaultElements.includes(tag),
  );

  // Add custom elements to the schema
  for (const tag of customTags) schema.addCustomElements(tag);
}

